# Infinite Scroller - doesn't work on side bar drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

```
$(window).on('scroll.infinite', function(){
       console.log('scroll fnc!');
        if($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
            //do load
        }  
    });
```

I have the above, which is used to load new data in when the user hits the bottom of the screen.

The problem is, it only works when using a mouse wheel, if you grab the side bar and scroll down it doesn't work, any ideas why? It's nothing to do with measurement as the log doesn't even run.

Answer (score 0):

It works on a plain div for both scroll wheel and dragging

```
$('.scroll').on('scroll.infinite', function(){
    console.log("scrolling with infinite scroll");
});
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rq9j/))

Maybe you should consider wrapping your content in a div if that doesn't look weird.

Comment: You mean this solution is not viable, or the fiddle does not work on your computer? If so, could you specify what browser you are targeting (and possibly what OS) ?